# Fcm badge not show in android

Tags: android

I am implementing fcm with backend as python, i need badge app icon whenever push notification came but it not working on most of android phone except moto g android 7.

i did in AndroidManifest.xml :

```
    <service
        android:name=".fcmnotification.Custom_FirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <service
        android:name=".fcmnotification.Custom_FirebaseInstanceIDService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

This is my meta-data in AndroidManifest.xml :

```
 <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
        android:resource="@drawable/pushlogo"
        tools:ignore="ManifestResource"/>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
        android:resource="@color/colorPrimary" />
```

Answer (score 6):

Badge App icon was introduced in Nougat i.e Android 7 for Stock Android phones. Hence, your above code it work on Moto G Android 7 and not versions previous to it. 
Now, to fix it on previous android versions you need to understand that Badge Icon in app launchers are launcher specific. 
Best way to achieve previous version support is to use this lib : [ShortcutBadger](https://github.com/leolin310148/ShortcutBadger)

Comment: Thanks dear for answer.